# issue/bug using SelectTokens with JsonPath

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonpath

I have an issue using NewtonSoft v8.0.3 JToken.SelectTokens() with a specific JsonPath. To reproduce issue in C#:

```
        string json = "[{\"name\":\"string\",\"value\":\"aString\"},{\"name\":\"number\",\"value\":123},{\"name\":\"array\",\"value\":[1,2,3,4]},{\"name\":\"object\",\"value\":{\"1\":1}}]";
        string path = "$.[?(@.value!=null)]";
        string newJson = String.Empty;

        JToken jt = JToken.Parse(json);
        IEnumerable<JToken> tokens = jt.SelectTokens(path, false);
        newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tokens, Formatting.Indented);
        // Output is missing objects and arrays??
        // newJson = [{"name": "string","value": "aString"},{"name": "number","value": 123}]
```

Running above code will not return any objects or arrays?! Is there a bug in JToken.SelectTokens() of Json.Net?

To validate the path I have used http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/ which works fine, see this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3f5v96p/1/)

I hope someone can shine some light on this.

**UPDATE:**
Thought this issue occured as we are trying to use "null" value, but no matter what inequality query I run, no {} / [] is returned from JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out what was causing the .SelectTokens to ignore arrays and objects when using JSONPath. The issues occurs in [QueryExpressions.cs line 78](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath/QueryExpression.cs#L78)

```
JValue v = r as JValue;
```

This will cause any JToken that is JObject/JArray to become **null** and hence being ignored when compared. My way of fixing this was to replace line 78 with the following code that handles JObject and JArray:

```
            JValue v = null;
            switch (r.Type)
            {
                case JTokenType.Object:
                case JTokenType.Array:
                    v = new JValue(r.ToString());
                    break;
                default:
                    v = r as JValue;
                    break;
            }
```

This will ensure that JObject and JArray are returned when calling .SelectTokens. Please feel free to comment solution or suggest alternative and better aproaches.

**UPDATE: Happy to inform that this issue been fixed with new releases. See [GITHUB](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commit/031222d4f4bd541e66f236329591f2427f835174) for more information.**

Comment: I ham happy to inform that this issue been fixed with new releases. See https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commit/031222d4f4bd541e66f236329591f2427f835174 for more information.

Answer (score 3):

I can make [`SelectTokens()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm) return the results you want by using the existence operator rather than the inequality operator:

```
string path = "$.[?(@.value)]";
```

Now all 4 objects are returned.  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xpmzjW).

As to whether this is a bug, the [JSONPath article](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) is ambiguous.  It says:

> ```
> []   ?()     applies a filter (script) expression.
> n/a   ()     script expression, using the underlying script engine.
> ```

But what does *using the underlying script engine* actually mean?  If I test your JSON and query expression at https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/, then an error is generated for both `Flow Communications JSONPath 0.3.1` and `Stefan Goessner JSONPath 0.8.3`.  If I use my existence query, then the former works correctly but the latter still throws an exception.

Should Json.NET behave as it does currently?  The present implementation implicitly provides the ability to filter for properties that have primitive values.  The proposed behavior would *lose* this capability.  I.e., any object or array value would always match any inequality operator such as `"$.[?(@.value!='aString')]"`, which might not be expected.

**Update**

Your clarified requirement is to run a query `"$.[?(@.value!=null)]"` to return all objects with a property named `"value"` that exists and has non-null value, regardless of whether that value is a primitive or a nested container.

One the one hand, this seems like a reasonable query that ought to be possible.  On the other, the current capability of being able to run inequality queries on primitive values without also getting all container values seems useful and should also be possible.  And either interpretation of that particular query string seems plausible; the JSONPath language definition is just too vague and leaves too much up to the interpretation of implementers.

Your options to get what you need include:

1. You could certainly [report an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) about this.  Newtonsoft could decide that the current behavior is wrong, and change it.
2. You could fork your own version of Json.NET and modify [`BooleanQueryExpression.IsMatch(JToken t)`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath/QueryExpression.cs#L87) as follows:

   ```
               case QueryOperator.NotEquals:
                   if (v != null && !EqualsWithStringCoercion(v, Value))
                   {
                       return true;
                   }
                   else if (v == null && r != null)
                   {
                       return true;
                   }
                   break;
   ```
3. You could use the following workaround:

   ```
   var path = "$.[?(@.value)]";
   var tokens = jt.SelectTokens(path, false)
       .Where(t => !t["value"].IsNull());
   ```

   using the extension method:

   ```
   public static class JsonExtensions
   {
       public static bool IsNull(this JToken token)
       {
           return token == null || token.Type == JTokenType.Null;
       }
   }
   ```

Finally, you ask *What I don't understand is why it works fine in javascript, but not in selectTokens of the Json.Net.*.  The reason that Json.NET is behaving differently than, say, http://jsonpath.com/, is that:

1. The standard is completely ambiguous as to what a `script expression` is, exactly, and
2. They are implemented using different technologies and code bases.  Json.NET interprets `(@.value!=null)` to mean

   > a value of type `JValue` named "value" that is not equal to the `null` json primitive.

   whereas the other parser interprets the query as

   > a value named "value" that is not equal to the `null` json primitive.

   The fact that c# is strongly typed as compared to, say, javascript, may explain the difference.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Sorry, but should have mentioned that the whole purpose of "$.[?(@.value!=null)]" is to only return the objects where key "value" have values. The challenge is to avoid returning ie. **{"name":"testnull","value":null}. Regarding the JSONPath tests online, there are some differences I dont understand why. Testing on the site you mention, I did notice errors, however; on www.jsonpath.com or www.jsonquerytool.com it works with "$.[?(@.value!=null)]". What I dont understand is why it works fine in javascript, but not in selectTokens of the Json.Net. Any ideas on fix?

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for clarifying. WIll report as an issue and start investigate option 2 as I dont want an static check for "value" key using LINQ. Might be another name for key in other JSON.

Comment: UPDATE: Hey, today I noticed that I've been misslead. The returning of object/arrays is not depending on the JsonPath $.[?(@.value!=null)] - It does not matter what inequality query you run. For example, I tested $.[?(@.value!='string')] and this will not return objects/arrays aswell.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard implementation of Jsonpath, so your results will vary depending upon which parser you are using.  However, you should never need to check for nulls, as it doesn't really make sense with Jsonpath.

This is what you need:

```
var result = jt.SelectTokens("$.[?(@.value)]");
```

Comment: I think you have missunderstood the qustion and issue. I am not checking for nulls, I'm avoiding to return potential tokens where the objects key "value" might be null using JsonPath. The problem have been identified and reported to Newtonsoft.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I tried it in my browser and didn't bother to verify that Json.NET matched the behavior.  However, my point still stands about the '!=null' is still unnecessary -- if/when the bug is fixed, the Jsonpath I posted should give you the results you want.